# Set ENV from external script (secret Manager) in docker

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to integrate aws secret manager with Docker. I have to call secret manager and set response JSON to the ENV.
My JSON looks like this

```
{
"username": "demo_user",
"password": "some_password"
}
```

I am trying below steps to set ENV
`Dockerfile`

```
RUN export secretData=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id /secret/id --region region-example-north-1);echo $secretData;

RUN bash -l -c 'echo export $secretData="$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id /secret/id --region region-example-north-1)" >> /etc/bash.bashrc'
```

Both methods of RUN didn't work for me. I want output something like `ENV RUN export secretData`

My Env variables are username and password so further this output will be stored in each variable respectively

Thanks is advance for each reply.

Comment: While it’s possible to do what you want, it’s not best practice from security point of view because your aws credentials might stay in docker image.

Comment: I have implement in project for all but for this case only I have implement in docker

Comment: Why you need that username/password when you build image? Can you arrange so that you only make use of them when you run the image?

Comment: You can capture the json value with jq and do RUN with export key. ENV is key value pair, it should be clear how you set it, not inheriting from previous component format i.e. json from secret manager.
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <ARN> --region <REGION> | jq -r '.SecretString' | jq '."username"' --raw-output. But overall this is bad practice, you can inject the env during the docker runs instead.